# describe the set of prime numbers that can divide integers of the form $n^2 + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Describe the set of prime numbers that can divide integers of the form $n^2 + 1$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Then, prove that the set of primes occurring is infinite.

So far what I came up with is that by Euler’s criterion, $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1\equiv0{\pmod{p}}$. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: If $p$ divides $n^2+1$, then $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely forgot about that.

Comment: By using $\Phi_{2^k}(n)$ you may easily prove that there are infinite primes $\equiv 1\pmod{2^k}$. You question is just the $k=2$ instance.

Comment: It is the set of primes that are not congruent to $3$ modulo $4.$  If $S$ is a finite non-empty collection of primes then $1+(\prod_{p\in S}p)^2$ is divisible  by  a prime $p \not \in S$  and $p\not \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group with identity $1$ and if $G$ has an even number of members then $\exists x\in G\;(x^2=1\ne x).$...  For prime $p$ such that $4|(p-1),$ let $G$ be the non-zero square residues mod $p$ with multiplication mod $p$.  For some $x\in G$ we have $x^2\equiv 1\not \equiv x \mod p.$ Since $x\equiv y^2$ for some $y\in \Bbb Z$ we have $(y^2)^2\equiv 1 \not \equiv y^2  ,$ so $y^2\equiv -1.$

Comment: Suggest you take $n = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,$ factor those nine $n^2 + 1,$ write down the prime factors found this way. Look for patterns among those found so far.